# How to create a fluid 2-column GridLayout within a ScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jscrollpane, grid-layout

I have done tons of searching over the past two hours, and I've given up. The image below shows what I am trying to achieve (don't judge my drawing it's late and I made it in paint quickly):

[image]

Basically, I want a JScrollPane to have a JPanel with a 2-column GridLayout, and as I add elements I want the GridLayout to expand downward. I want the elements to use their Preferred Size and to NOT expand within the GridLayout.

Currently I have a `JScrollPane` and a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`, and a `JPanel` containing the grid with a `FlowLayout`. As a test, I add 10 buttons to the grid. Here's my current code:

```
// Setup main panel
JPanel pnlUsers = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
pnlUsers.setOpaque(true);
pnlUsers.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

// Setup GridLayout Container
JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
pnl2.setOpaque(false);
pnl2.add(pnlusers);

// Setup scrollpane
JScrollPane scrUsers = new JScrollPane(pnl2);
scrUsers.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrUsers.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrUsers.setOpaque(false);
scrUsers.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
scrUsers.setBorder(null);

// Add users
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pnlUsers.add(new JButton("Button " + (i + 1));
}
```

This gives a very good result, with the buttons using their preferred size as seen in the image below:

[image]

Unfortunately, the buttons are still not filling the horizontal space. So, I attempted to make pnl2 a BoxLayout instead and add some vertical glue...

```
// Setup GridLayout Container
JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
pnl2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnl2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
pnl2.setOpaque(false);
pnl2.add(pnlusers);
pnl2.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

I also created my own temporary button class that sets the preferred size to use the minimum size:

```
public class TempButton extends JButton {

    public PLTempButton(String msg) {
        super(msg);
        this.setPreferredSize(this.getMinimumSize());
    }

}
```

Which resulted in the following:

[image]

This is much better, but there's still a problem. If there are not enough buttons to cause the JScrollPane to scroll, the buttons height are not consistent and will resize as you resize the window vertically. Why?

Obviously when I add 100 buttons, they use their preferred size:

[image]

Maybe I'm just not understanding the differences between minimum, preferred and maximum size? But I want the buttons to use the height they're set even if there aren't enough to cause the scroll-pane to, well, scroll. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'd consider a `JTable`

Comment: *... but they need to expand in width.* - not sure what that means. When using a `GridLayout` all components are made the same size. If your components have different widths then you would need to use a `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: What I mean is that the JPanel using the GridLayout needs to expand to fill the horizontal space

Comment: @FireController1847, well you have two suggestions. Don't forget to "accept" the answer the helped solve the problem by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem is solved.

Comment: @camickr Yes, my apologies I posted this before I went to bed so I haven't had a chance to try them out yet

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How do I even get a GridLayout within a ScrollPane?

1. Create a `JPanel`
2. Apply a `GridLayout` to the `JPanel`
3. Wrap the `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane`

For example

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
// Add the scroll pane to what ever parent container you're using
```

> 2) How do I get said GridLayout to expand horizontally, including the added components?

That doesn't make sense with regards to all previous part of the question, you said *"and have it slowly expand downward the more things I add"*

Having said that, the "basic" answer is, you configure the `GridLayout` and let it do it's job.  The above example is configured for 2 columns and n number of roes

> 3) How would I add a "margin" to the components?

That's a broad answer, you could:

- Make use of the horizontal and vertical gap properties of the `GridLayout`
- Use a compound layout and adjust the insets of the an appropriate layout manager (like `GridBagLayout`)

## Recommendations

I would recommend reading through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get a better understanding of the layout managers.

Remember, you not stuck to using one.

I would also recommend reading through [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) as you're asking basic questions about the API which are better covered through the tutorials

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer and your information is much appreciated. I'll be sure to read up on both of those to remind myself. However this unfortunately didn't answer my question. I've updated the question to provide more information and be more specific on what I was looking for :)

Comment: *"Maybe I'm just not understanding the differences between minimum, preferred and maximum size? But I want the buttons to use the height they're set even if there aren't enough to cause the scroll-pane to, well, scroll. What can I do to fix this?"* - Use a `GridBagLayout` instead

Answer (score 0):

The following mre demonstrates creating a `JPanel` with `GridLayout` warped by `JScrollPane` and setting its horizontal and vertival gaps. 
The `Jpanel` is added using a `BorderLayout`  (the default layout manager of `JFrame` content pane) which allows it to expand:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class SwingMain {

    private String text ="Growing ";
    private JPanel grid;
    private JFrame f;

    SwingMain() {
        creategui();
    }

    void creategui(){

        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JButton addComponentBtn = new JButton("Add Component");
        addComponentBtn.addActionListener(e-> addComponent());
        f.add(addComponentBtn, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10)); //any number of rows, 2 columns, H and V gap
        f.add(new JScrollPane(grid), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void addComponent() {
        grid.add(new JLabel(text) );
        text +="."; //make text longer so JLable grows
        f.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingMain();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer and your information is much appreciated. However this unfortunately didn't answer my question. I've updated the question to provide more information and be more specific on what I was looking for :)

Comment: I think it did answer your question but probably did not solve the problem you are trying to solve. I also think changing a question after it has been answered is not a good practice. Answers that seem to be unrelated to the question may be confusing for a future reader. I would recommend posting a new question.